# JavaScript New Tab when OnClick on Select/Option

Tags: javascript, html

How to open a new tab through a url inserted in Select / Option with onClick trigger?

I'm Trying this:

```js
function fOpenNewTab(url) {
  var varOpenNewTab = window.open(url, '_blank');
  varOpenNewTab.focus();
}
```

```html
<select name="name1" id="id1">
  <option onclick="fOpenNewTab('https://example.net/Apps/page.php?id=49');">New Page with ID: 49</option>
  <option onclick="fOpenNewTab('https://example.net/Apps/page.php?id=57');">New Page with ID: 57</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You could use window.open()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onchange` event inside the `select` tag to achieve your result. Check the code below:

```js
function fOpenNewTab(event) {
  var OpenNewTab = window.open(event.value, '_blank');
}
```

```html
<select name="name1" id="id1" onchange="fOpenNewTab(this)">

  <option value="https://example.net/Apps/page.php?id=49">New Page with ID: 49</option>
  <option value="https://example.net/Apps/page.php?id=57">New Page with ID: 57</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

- You need the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) of the select since options do not have event handlers.
- You need a "please select" to allow the change to trigger

I suggest you add the focus to the target page since you may get an error when you try to focus a page that is not on the same server as the script

```js
document.getElementById("id1").addEventListener("change",function() {
  const loc = this.value;
  if (loc) {
    const varOpenNewTab = window.open(loc, '_blank');
    if (varOpenNewTab) varOpenNewTab.focus();
    else alert("sorry, blocked by popup blocker or sandboxing");
  }  
})
```

```html
<select name="name1" id="id1">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="https://example.net/Apps/page.php?id=49">New Page with ID: 49</option>
  <option value="https://example.net/Apps/page.php?id=57">New Page with ID: 57</option>

</select>
```

Comment: The other answer from @harshana was the most suitable for what I meant, although yours also works and is a useful answer for someone who needs it in the future. Who knows for me.. TY again.